# add li element in ul using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try make simple todo list. This is my html code:

```
<form>
   Task: <input type="text" name="task" id="input">
   <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<br>

<h2>What you need to do</h2>
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Then I try use jquery to read from i input field and apppend to existing ul element. But when i try it in chrome my new added element show me for half of second and remove.
Here is my js code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
            var new_task = $('#input').val();
            $('#list').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your form is submitted when you click your button, and so your page reloads.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/QBrPn/

Answer (score 10):

A button inside a form has a default type of submit, and will submit the form, you need to prevent that or set a different type on the button :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var new_task = $('#input').val();
        $('#list').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd also add a `$('#input').val('');` after the `.append()` call for improved usability.

Comment: @adeneo Why does everyone insist on using preventDefault() instead of return false; ? returning false has the added benefit of also calling stopPropagation() in jQuery

Comment: @Precastic - That's because some of us thinks it an abuse of the return operator to return false when all we are really trying to do is prevent the default action, and preventDefault would be the right tool for that.

Comment: As a sidenote, that's also why you almost always will find preventDefault in the documentation for jQuery, and not return false, see for instance the [documentation for on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @adeneo OK. Thanks. As a note jQuery only have it in the docs to describe the difference between the 2 functions ;)

Comment: @Precastic - I guess that's sort of true, as the documentation is supposed to describe the difference, and it also mentions that return false is a shortcut for both, and for this example it doesn't really matter which one we use, but we don't need to return anything, nor do we need to stop the propagation, all we need to do is prevent the default action, so why not use the method that does that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

HTML

```
<form>
  Task: <input type="text" name="task" id="input">
  <button>Submit</button>
  <br>

 <h2>What you need to do</h2>
 <ul id="list">

 </ul>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button').click(function() {

  var new_task = $('#input').val();
  $('#list').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
  return false;
 });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FLy4M/)

Answer (score 3):

You must `return false;` at the end of your function:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var new_task = $('#input').val();
  $('#list').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
  return false;   // This is new line of code
});
```